# sum of integers inside a specific range using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, sum

A simple way of solving my problem would be the following method:

```
public int sum(int num)
{
    if(num == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return num + sum(num - 1);
}
```

My problem starts when I try to solve the same problem using the following recursive definition:
"The sum of 1 to N is the sum of 1 to N/2 plus the sum of N/2 + 1 to N".

I tried the following but I'm stuck in an infinite loop...

```
public int sum(int max, int base)
{

    if(max == base)
        return base;
    else
        return max/2 + sum(max/2 - 1, 1) + max + sum(max-1, max/2 + 1); 
}
```

I can't seem to find a way forward...

Comment: how max and base relate to N? and what if base is more than max?

Comment: Is this your homework !?

Comment: Hint: start by renaming your parameters too lowerBoundary and higherBoundary for example. Because that is what they actually *mean*; and alone that might help you to figure the "correct" way of invoking your method.

Comment: look at those inputs : max = 2 and base = 1

Comment: input (3,1) and return 1+sum(0,1)+3+... and as for sum(0,1,) now max<base and then it will come into infinite.

Comment: @Zorglube: no. i'm learning recursion and solved the problem I presented above (the "simple" way).
I'm just trying to make it a little harder for myself

Comment: @M.Reif, I know. those are the simple cases I tested, and that's why I asked this question here

Comment: @GabrielEdery did you tried the example i told you? do you understand it?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, try something like this

```
@Test
public void recursive(){
    int number = 20;
    System.out.println(sum(0, number));
    System.out.println(sum(0, number/2));
    System.out.println(sum(number/2 +1, number));
    Assert.assertThat(sum(0, number), is(sum(0, number/2) + sum(number/2 +1, number)));
}

private int sum(int origin, int end) {
    if(origin == end)
        return end;
    return origin + sum(origin+1, end);
}
```

Comment: @Gabriel: please *do* run this: this is a basic debugging technique you'll need through your career.  I'm still using it after four decades in the field, and it's my most useful weapon.  If you have a sick patient, ask it to tell you where things don't feel good.